# Angular 2. Rebuild form control(s)

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-forms

Is there a way to force Angular form to recreate it's controls? I mean creating new instances? Looks like it only creates them on initial load. Not sure if I really need it but here's my issue:

I have an "edit" control which has an `@Input() set item(editItem)` of the item I need to edit. I set this item from its parent and the control should reset the form values.
Within a form I use my own custom dropdown control which has bindable list of options.

Generally it looks like this:

```js
    @Component({
      template:`
        <form [formGroup]="form">
          <my-control [items]="items" formControlName="itemId"></app-combobox>
        </form>
      `

    export class EditComponent implements OnInit {
      items = [{text: 'Item 1', itemId: 1}, {text: 'Item 2', itemId: 2}];

      @Input() set editItem(item) {
        //if some logic...
          this.items = [{text: 'Item 3', itemId: 3}, {text: 'Item 4', itemId: 4}];

        this.initForm(item);
      }

      constructor(private _fb: FormBuilder) {}

      ngOnInit(): void {
        this.initForm();
      }

      initForm(item?) {
        this.form = this._fb.group({
          // itemId could differ and should be in the items list before binding happens
          'itemId': [item ? item.itemId : null]
      }
    }
```

and the control:

```js
    export class ComboboxComponent implements ControlValueAccessor {
      items = [];

      @Input() set items(list[]) {
        this.items = list;
        this.updateValue();
      }

      // ControlValueAccessor implementation
      writeValue(value: any) {
         this.updateValue();
      }

      updateValue() {
        // here we try to use a newly updated list (but it's not updated yet!)
      }
    }
```

And the problem is that even if I set a new list of items before creating new formGroup the form binding happens before my items list binding. The `writeValue` method from the `ControlValueAccessor` interface gets called before `@Input() set items([])` on my dropdown control.

I can use `setTimeout(() => this.updateValue())` inside the `writeValue` and it seems to help but I don't like this solution. How can I make control property binding to happen before form binding? Calling timeout or forcing Angular to detect changes before `initForm()` doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

The way I do something similar is to set up the form structure in the ngOnInit something like this:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.productForm = this.fb.group({
        productName: ['', [Validators.required,
                           Validators.minLength(3),
                           Validators.maxLength(50)]],
        productCode: ['', Validators.required],
        starRating: ['', NumberValidators.range(1, 5)],
        tags: this.fb.array([]),
        description: ''
    });
```

And then I don't change that when the data changes. Rather, I just update the values on the form with code like this:

```
onProductRetrieved(product: IProduct): void {
    if (this.productForm) {
        this.productForm.reset();
    }
    this.product = product;

    // Update the data on the form
    this.productForm.patchValue({
        productName: this.product.productName,
        productCode: this.product.productCode,
        starRating: this.product.starRating,
        description: this.product.description
    });
    this.productForm.setControl('tags', this.fb.array(this.product.tags || []));
}
```

You could call this from your @Input setter.

Comment: Thank you. That doesn't seem to work for me either tough I didn't use fb.array (does it do any magic?) but tried to move my items into a form control and bind to it. Changes are not detected.
The only way I made it to work is to reference dropdown as a child and set it's `items` property directly. Then it happens immediately and before form databinding.